# Removing empty plots with `facet_grid`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to remove empty plots while using `facet_grid`.

The names of the labels in columns is arbitrary (*e.g.* `foo`, `baz`), but I only have two columns.
I have an empty plot, like this:

[image: example 1]

I would like to remove empty plots, like this (thank you GIMP):

[image: example 2]

Contrary to the example, the names are not systematic, and the number of plots in the top and in the bottom does not necessarily match.
The plots can be ordered as:

```
+-----+-----+
| foo | bar |
+-----+-----+
| baz |     |
+-----+-----+
```

(with the last plot being empty.)

I guess I could use `grid.arrange`, but I would then have to split my plot into a list of plots.

Any other solution?

Comment: I would use one of the packages for arranging plots. Since this is a common problem, I made some notes (mainly for myself) about it here: https://biolitika.si/how-to-combine-plots-and-table-made-with-ggplot-or-grid-graphics-in-r.html Note that `cowplot::ggplot` is now `cowplot::ggplot2` but I haven't gotten around to fixing the post.

Comment: can you give a reproducible example? You could just delete the empty rows?

Comment: @andschar `facet_grid` will not omit empty combination of variables.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I guess using `cowplot` or `grid.extra` would be the most sensible method...

Comment: So you want a `facet_grid` label on x-axis as three-way? And then hide the x-axis, pertinent for graph analysis. Yes, as is this will not be possible with `ggplot2` + `facet_grid`. You will need a customized approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example where I try to reproduce your problem:

```
dts <- read.table(text="
x y  g1 g2
1 1  1 B
2 2  1 B
1 1  1 D
2 2  1 D
1 1  1 F
2 2  1 F
1 1  2 A
2 2  2 A
1 1  2 C
2 2  2 C
1 1  2 E
2 2  2 E
", header=T
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=dts, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(g1~g2) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

My simple suggestion is to use `facet_wrap` instead of `facet_grid`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=dts, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(g1~g2) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: this does not work if you really want your rows to have a meaning and if the number of columns in each row is not even. For example, I would like to have rows by data$MyFeature, and columns by data$myField, but using facet_wrap, I won't be able to cut at the right place... Do you know a solution?